# Align Multiple Lines of Text Vertically With Image

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

How do I have a list of items, and align the text (most often multiple lines) to the middle of an image to the left of the text?  I have tried numerous approaches (line-height, absolute position, etc), but nothing has worked.  Here is an example of what I would like it to look like.

If I can do something with Foundation, I'm using that as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use display:table together with display:table-cell as shown in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UMxW/).
Also don't use background-images for icons unless you don't have them in vector/SVG format, in you'r case it looks like you can get those icons from a free icon set.

Go to [fontello.com](http://fontello.com) or similar and create a font there (like I have in my example) and use that custom font you created.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <i class="icon-glass"></i>
        <p>This will be a day long remembered. It has seen the end of Kenobi, and will soon see the end of the rebellion.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <i class="icon-music"></i>
        <p>If this is a consular ship, where is the ambassador? — Commander, tear this ship apart until you’ve found those plans. And bring me the passengers, I want them alive!If this is a consular ship, where is the ambassador? — Commander, tear this ship apart until you’ve found those plans. And bring me the passengers, I want them alive!</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
        <p>Look, good against remotes is one thing, good against the living, that’s something else.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
p {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
i {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 40px;
}
```

If you don't like using `display: table`, add a "ghost element" with the `:before` selector which works good together with `display: inline-block`. Read more about vertical align at this [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple HTML table.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If that's possible in your context, I'd suggest setting the image as `background-image` for your text container, with `background-position: left`, and adding a `padding-left` to avoid having the text on top of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nWf7j/).

HTML:

```
<div class="item"> 
    <span class="helper"></span>    
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoQHBx4nEdsNbXh8aZ-RT1ID6yLFwZkLV6MwGlVcIXWf_YbzQF6w" />
    <div class="caption">
Jesse Jackson? Do you even... ah, I see you have a telephone at least. You know that blinking thing I've been calling you on? I will break this, I will BREAK THIS. Damn druggie idiot. Is this what you've been doing the whole time I've been trying to reach you? 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    width: 400px;
    height: 90px;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}

.item img {
    vertical-align: middle;    
    height: 60px;
}

.item div.caption {
    width: 340px;
    float: right;
}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Alternatively you could do the following (this even works if the height of each row is not fixed):

```
.item {
    width: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;   
    background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoQHBx4nEdsNbXh8aZ-RT1ID6yLFwZkLV6MwGlVcIXWf_YbzQF6w);
    background-position: left center;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.item div.caption {
    width: 340px;
    float: right;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWf7j/3/)

Comment: That looks like what I need, but check it out if the text gets shorter than the image: http://jsfiddle.net/nWf7j/1/

Comment: Can you assume a fixed height for your use case?